# How do I quickly tell the structural differences between two databases?

Tags: mysql, upgrade, schema

I am upgrading a web application to a newer version and need to migrate the data manually. The newer version uses slightly different database structure. It has added a few tables, but all of the old tables still exist with the same name. **How can I quickly see if any of the new tables are differently structured than the old ones?**

Both databases (the old structure and the new structure) currently exist on the same server. The new one is empty, but the old one still has all the original data. I only have access to the server through ssh and the MySQL cli (no phpMyAdmin or GUI desktop applications [like this one](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-database-diff-report.html)).

Version information: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)`